# How to create a hyperlink within a PDF using ColdFusion, so that this hypelink will open in a new browser tab?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, hyperlink, coldfusion-9

I am creating a PDF dynamically using cfdocument tag of ColdFusion 9. A hyperlink is there in the body of this dynamically created PDF. I am opening this PDF in browser, now when I am clicking the hyperlink, it is opening in the same tab even if I have added target="_blank" to that hyperlink. So, is there any way to open this hyperlink in a new browser tab?

Here are the sample code,

```
    <cfdocument format="pdf" filename="D:\test\newpdf.pdf" overwrite="yes" mimetype="text/html">
      For more help <a href="https://www.google.co.in/" target="_blank">click here</a>.
    </cfdocument>
```

Please help.

Comment: @KobbyPemson, I have tried with both javascript and jQuery, but neither of these two works.

Comment: Maybe try target="_new" instead?

Comment: Will 'target' even work in a PDF? Just because you can view a PDF in a browser does not mean that it will work as a web page. If you were to open the PDF in a PDF reader, like Acrobat, it would not matter what the 'target' is. PDFs are a different beast than web pages, expecting them to work like web pages might be an exercise in futility.

Comment: Does this help? http://answers.acrobatusers.com/How-I-open-hyperlinks-inside-embedded-pdf-window-q2104.aspx

Comment: The target attribute might not work but it's certainly worth an attempt.

Comment: @Raymond Camden, target="_new" is not working.

Comment: @Matt Busche, I think the answer you are suggesting will work only if we are creating the pdf from Acrobat. But in this case, I am creating the pdf dynamically in ColdFusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple HTML. You need to open the link before the execution o your CFML page. So, if you want to open the tab with the PDF you should call it for execute in a new table

> ```
> <a href="mycfmAsPDF.cfm" target="_blank">Link</a>
> ```

Code for your mycfmAsPDF.cfm

> ```
>    <cfdocument format="pdf" filename="D:\test\newpdf.pdf" overwrite="yes" mimetype="text/html">
>  For more help <a href="https://www.google.co.in/" target="_blank">click here</a>.
> ```

Comment: I am not sure, what are you trying to suggest? It seems, you have just copied and pasted my sample code. Can you please explain your answer?

Comment: you're saying that your link inside you pdf file are opening in the same page, ignoring the _blank target, is it?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.